# Can I do a where on a sub select table from the outer select

Tags: mysql

Say for example I have this query, that I want to use as a `VIEW` "user_data"

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        big_tbl.user_id,
        COUNT(big_tbl.id) as `total`
    FROM
        big_tbl
    GROUP BY 
        big_tbl.user_id
) a
```

If I do `SELECT * FROM user_data`, it takes around 10 seconds to run. If I do `SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE user_id = 1234` it takes around 10 seconds to run. If I do this it takes sub 1 second

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        big_tbl.user_id,
        COUNT(big_tbl.id) as `total`
    FROM
        big_tbl
    WHERE
        big_tbl.user_id = 1234
    GROUP BY 
        big_tbl.user_id
) a
```

Is there anyway I could do something like `SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE big_tbl.user_id = 1234`? Or is this just not possible to do with my currect approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to comprehend. If i understand correct what you ask, user_id must live in both tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_data
WHERE user_id =
      (SELECT user_id
       FROM big_tbl
       WHERE user_id = 1234);
```

Comment: I think the problem is `user_data` isn't a table, it's a `VIEW`, and when the view is calculating all the data with no `where` that's when it's slow.

Comment: @TomHart if 'a' table has an 'a.user_id' field, and you have alter provileges in the database you can alter the view. If that is the case search for alter view.